# ADF ClaimProcessor Performance Considerations

Tags: ambient-data-framework

When an ADF ClaimProcessor is added to the framework, is there any documentation available to describe the lifespan of ClaimProcessor objects created? I am trying to understand more deeply how this will affect website performance.

I am assuming there are just two possibilities:

1. The framework just creates a single instance of the ClaimProcessor for the application? If so, do I need to worry about multi-threading?
2. The framework creates one instance of the ClaimProcessor per visitor session, and therefore if there is configuration that needs to be loaded in a constructor it will happen once per visitor. If this is the case, how long does the session last before garbage collection clears up un-used objects?

edit: Adding to my original question(s) above, what would be the performance impact of having two ClaimProcessors that add functionally distinct claims vs. combining the processors into one.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK The ADF creates only one instance per ClaimProcessor when the servlet is initialized, and an Engine is created with the configuration file.

This is done in the init of the `Engine` class:

```
    try
    {
      claimProcessors.put(cpd.getUri(), cpd.getImplementationClass().newInstance());
    }
```

Then when a user makes a request, then the only difference between two processors or one combined, would be two function calls or one, in the list of `requestStartClaimProcessors`. but I don't think the performance impact will be noticeable.